# Substituting an exception for a value during a trace

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7

In python (2.7.5) , when `settrace`ing a target program, is there a way, whenever an exception in the program being traced occur, to substitute the exception for a normal return value (thus, clearing up the exceptional state and proceeding normally with the execution)? How?

Answer (score 0):

Finally ended up reading python's source code. There is no way to do that. The function responsible to setup the trace call is [call_exc_trace](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L3875), which resets the frame data associated with exceptions and, after the user tracing function ends, restores the old values.

This is a pity, and also explains why PDB has no features like reseting exceptions or returning immediately a value (PDB's `return` command actually *continues* until the end of the function).